# Prove that $\int_{-1}^{1} 4x \sqrt{1-x^{2}}\, dx = -3\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

What is of interest is the assertion
$$\int_{-1}^{1} 4x \sqrt{1-x^{2}}\,dx = -3\pi.$$

Since 
$$\pi = 2\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\,dx,$$
i.e. the area of a unit circle,
it suffices to prove that
$$\int_{-1}^{1}x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\,dx = -\frac{3}{2}\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\,dx.$$
But I did not see the left-hand side can be equal to the right-hand side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The integrand $4 x \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ is odd and the domain $[-1, 1]$ of integration is symmetric around the origin, so by symmetry the integral is zero:
$$\int_{-1}^1 4x \sqrt{1 - x^2} \,dx = 0.$$

Comment: Yeah, thanks. The assertion is wrong.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You could try the following substitution : $x=cos(u)$ or $x=sin(u)$

Comment: You beat me to it +1

Answer (score 3):

$x=\sin \theta \implies dx= \cos \theta \ d\theta$

$\displaystyle\int x \sqrt{1-x^2}\ dx=\displaystyle\int \sin \theta \cos^2\theta\ d\theta$

$\cos^2 \theta=z \implies -2\sin \theta\cos \theta\ d\theta=dz$

$\therefore \displaystyle\int \sin \theta \cos^2\theta\ d\theta=-\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int \sqrt{z}\ dz$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $u^2 = 1-x^2$. Use substitution.